# Error while npm start : author issue

Tags: json, node.js, reactjs, package.json, npm-start

I am getting an error while npm start in command prompt:

```
 package.json:
        { 

        "name": "reactapp",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "description": "",
        "main": "index.js",

        "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot",
        },
        "author": "safuwan",
        "license": "ISC",
        "dependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "react": "^16.4.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
        "webpack": "^4.14.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
      }
    }
```

[command prompt error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JXtY.png)

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"  remove comma after this then it work.

Comment: seems here json format issue that comma after ```"webpack-dev-server --hot"```, But better is you can put here what kind of error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You have extra comma (,) in your start script.

Here's how it should be:

```
package.json:
        { 

        "name": "reactapp",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "description": "",
        "main": "index.js",

        "scripts": {
        "start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
        },
        "author": "safuwan",
        "license": "ISC",
        "dependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
        "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
        "react": "^16.4.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
        "webpack": "^4.14.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
      }
    }
```